# Issues installing gtk2hs-buildtools

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, gtk, cabal

I am trying to install gtk3 for Haskell, but am having trouble with the gtk2hs-buildtools. I am following [these](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Linux) instructions. When I run the first line:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libcairo2-dev
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcairo2-dev is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Which is ok, but when I run:

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
```

I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1...
Warning: This package indirectly depends on multiple versions of the same
package. This is highly likely to cause a compile failure.
package gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1 requires array-0.4.0.1
package deepseq-1.3.0.1 requires array-0.4.0.1
package containers-0.5.0.0 requires array-0.4.0.1
package deepseq-1.3.0.2 requires array-0.5.0.0
package unix-2.6.0.1 requires bytestring-0.10.0.2
package unix-2.7.0.0 requires bytestring-0.10.4.0
package time-1.4.0.1 requires deepseq-1.3.0.1
package process-1.1.0.2 requires deepseq-1.3.0.1
package containers-0.5.0.0 requires deepseq-1.3.0.1
package bytestring-0.10.0.2 requires deepseq-1.3.0.1
package time-1.4.2 requires deepseq-1.3.0.2
package bytestring-0.10.4.0 requires deepseq-1.3.0.2
package process-1.1.0.2 requires directory-1.2.0.1
package gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1 requires directory-1.2.0.1
package unix-2.6.0.1 requires time-1.4.0.1
package random-1.0.1.1 requires time-1.4.0.1
package directory-1.2.0.1 requires time-1.4.0.1
package unix-2.7.0.0 requires time-1.4.2
package directory-1.2.0.1 requires time-1.4.2
package process-1.1.0.2 requires unix-2.6.0.1
package directory-1.2.0.1 requires unix-2.6.0.1
package directory-1.2.0.1 requires unix-2.7.0.0
Building gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1...
Preprocessing executable 'gtk2hsTypeGen' for gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1...
[1 of 2] Compiling Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools.hs, dist/build/gtk2hsTypeGen/gtk2hsTypeGen-tmp/Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( hierarchyGen/TypeGen.hs, dist/build/gtk2hsTypeGen/gtk2hsTypeGen-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/gtk2hsTypeGen/gtk2hsTypeGen ...
Preprocessing executable 'gtk2hsHookGenerator' for
gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1...
[1 of 2] Compiling Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools.hs, dist/build/gtk2hsHookGenerator/gtk2hsHookGenerator-tmp/Paths_gtk2hs_buildtools.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( callbackGen/HookGenerator.hs, dist/build/gtk2hsHookGenerator/gtk2hsHookGenerator-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/gtk2hsHookGenerator/gtk2hsHookGenerator ...
Preprocessing executable 'gtk2hsC2hs' for gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id directory-1.2.0.1-b345fe37c722587c0267eb05e0b3a77a: 
    directory-1.2.0.1-b345fe37c722587c0267eb05e0b3a77a is shadowed by package directory-1.2.0.1-91a788fd88acd7f149f0f10f5f1e23f2
    (use -v for more information)
Failed to install gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gtk2hs-buildtools-0.12.5.1 failed during the building phase. The exception
was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Checking the cabal version I have:

```
cabal -V
```

gives:

```
cabal-install version 1.18.0.3
using version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library
```

I have also made sure in my `.zshrc` to include:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The "official" guidance is that you should be using your *package manager* to install any Haskell stuff you want, not cabal(-install)*. You don't say what distro you are on, but I note that in Debian Sid there is a gtk2hs-buildtools. So you should do `apt-get gtk2hs-buildtools`; they will have sorted out the dependency issues already. Only use `cabal` for your own code.

*Personally, I install GHC manually, and use cabal-install for everything Haskell-related, but that's because I need the latest versions of a lot of stuff. It's really when you start mixing the two that you get in trouble.

Comment: Ok, something does install, but doing both `sudo apt-get install gtk3` or `cabal install gtk3` fails to install. Any advice on that?

Comment: Wait a sec, just noticed the red message at top... let met read through that. XD

Comment: What's the error message? (You should use `sudo apt-get install gtk3`, not `cabal install gtk3`.)

Comment: The error for apt-get is: E: Unable to locate package gtk3

Comment: Are you on Debian or Ubuntu or...?

Comment: I'm on Debian, so I can't be too much help. But the package you need to install might not be named exactly "gtk3". Try `aptitude search gtk3` and see if you can spot the package you want. On Debian, I see a bunch of packages that start with gtk3.

Comment: I have libgtk-3-dev installed, but it isn't really Haskell specific. Are you saying there should be a Haskell specific gtk3 distribution on apt-get?

Comment: Hmm, according to synaptic I also have libghc-gtk-dev installed, libghc-cario-dev, libghc-glib-dev, and libghc-pango-dev installed, which should allow me to build gtk3 stuff I believe...

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that's all you need.

Comment: It throws me an error when trying to compile saying: Cannot find module `Graphics.UI.Gtk`

Comment: You might want to start a new question, since this is a different problem than the one described in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, cabal tells you:

```
Warning: This package indirectly depends on multiple versions of the same
package. This is highly likely to cause a compile failure.
```

If you look at the versions of the dependencies, they don't matches. So the hell start!

As you want to use gtk3 I recommend to use the github repository, see installation instructions (at the end of the link): https://github.com/vincenthz/gtk2hs
Because the gtk and gtk3 libraries have the same name module (`import Graphics.UI.Gtk`), so ghc will not know which one to choose...

Hope it helps!